# How to Test React Beautiful DnD

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, drag-and-drop

````
After searching for examples on how to test react beautiful dnd I am still unable to get my tests to pass.
I am trying to simulate a drag and drop event and check that the table rows have been altered accordingly.

So I have a droppable table set up like this within my component :


```
<DragDropContext onDragEnd={handleDragEnd}>
                <Table sx={{ minWidth: 650,
                    borderCollapse: "separate",
                    borderSpacing: "0px 1rem" }}
                    aria-label="simple table">
                  <TableHead>
                    <TableRow>
                      {/* <TableCell sx={{color: "white", border: "0px solid"}}></TableCell> */}
                      <TableCell sx={{ color: "white", border: "0px solid" }}>ORDER</TableCell>
                      <TableCell sx={{ color: "white", border: "0px solid" }} align="center">TYPE</TableCell>
                      <TableCell sx={{ color: "white", border: "0px solid" }} align="left">CONTENT</TableCell>
                      <TableCell sx={{ color: "white", border: "0px solid" }} align="right">DELETE</TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                  </TableHead>
                  <Droppable droppableId="droppable-1">
                    {(provider) => (
                      <TableBody
                        ref={provider.innerRef}
                        {...provider.droppableProps}>
                        {tableData()}
                        {provider.placeholder}
                      </TableBody>
                    )}
                  </Droppable>
                </Table>
              </DragDropContext>
```

Where the 'handleDragEnd' looks like this :


``` 
const handleDragEnd = (e) => {
    if (!e.destination) return;
    let tempData = Array.from(informationData);
    let [source_data] = tempData.splice(e.source.index, 1);
    tempData.splice(e.destination.index, 0, source_data);
    props.dispatch(setGeneralItem("informationData", tempData));
  };
```


The test, looks like this :



```
test("Drag and drop", ()=>{
  jest.mock('react-beautiful-dnd', () => ({
    Droppable: ({ children }) => children({
      draggableProps: {
        key:{},
        draggableId:{},
        index:{},
        style: {},
        onDragEnd: jest.fn(),
      },
      innerRef: jest.fn(),
    }, {}),
    Draggable:
      // params to children are `provider`, `snapshot`
      ({ children }) => children({
        draggableProps: {
          style: {},
        },
        innerRef: jest.fn(),
      }, {}),
    DragDropContext: ({ children }) => children,
  }));

  jest.spyOn(actions, "setGeneralItem");

  let info = [
    { order: 1, dataType: "Text", contentUrl: "some text" },
    { order: 2, dataType: "Image", contentUrl: "someimageurl" },
    { order: 3, dataType: "Video", contentUrl: "somevideourl" },
  ]
  let tempData = [
    { order: 1, dataType: "Image", contentUrl: "someimageurl" },
    { order: 2, dataType: "Video", contentUrl: "somevideourl" },
    { order: 3, dataType: "Text", contentUrl: "some text" },
  ]

  store.dispatch(actions.setGeneralItem("informationData", info))
  let mockDispatch = (val) => { store.dispatch(val); }
  const { container } = render(
    renderWithStore(store, <Information {...props} dispatch={mockDispatch}/>));

    let dragStart = container.querySelectorAll('tr')[1].querySelectorAll('td')[1]
  let dropPosition = container.querySelectorAll('tr')[3].querySelectorAll('td')[1]

  fireEvent.dragStart(dragStart)
  fireEvent.drop(dropPosition)
  expect(actions.setGeneralItem).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(actions.setGeneralItem).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  expect(actions.setGeneralItem).toHaveBeenCalledWith("informationData", tempData);
})
```






In the test, I am assigning the row to move as dragStart, the row where I would like to drop my target as dropPosition and I try to simulate the change with the react testing library events dragStart and drop.
````

Unfortunately, this test fails on the last line. The last line checks to see that the table rows have been altered but it still dispatches the original info list instead of the tempData.

fireEvent.dragStart and fireEvent.drop don't seem to fire the event. I would like to know how to simulate this drag and drop event with the react-beautiful-dnd mock. I am not sure how to trigger the change.

```
Does anyone have any idea how to actually fire this drag and drop event?
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I've manged to simulate drag and drop not by firing the corresponding events but using the keybaord events. Although not the nicest solution the following should do the trick.

```
const SPACE = { keyCode: 32 };
const ARROW_DOWN = { keyCode: 40 };
fireEvent.keyDown(element, SPACE); // Begins the dnd
fireEvent.keyDown(element, ARROW_DOWN); // Moves the element
fireEvent.keyDown(element, SPACE); // Ends the dnd
```

Comment: You've got your keycodes backwards. ArrowDown is 40 and space is 32

Comment: The keyboard event approach is fantastic, but I couldn't use it. I am new to writing tests in react. Don't know what I am doing wrong, but somehow fireEvent.keyDown() or fireEvent.keyPress() simply doesn't work. I've also posted a [new question for this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77081297/7533126)

Comment: perfect, you save my life