# fireEvent.keyPress() and fireEvent.keyDown() not working in react testing library, while fireEvent.click() works for the same element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a checkbox which I want to test using keyPress. The checkbox should be checked on pressing the Space key.
Here's my Component file-

```js
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <input type="checkbox" data-testid="testing-it" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

And the test file-

```js
import { fireEvent, render } from "@testing-library/react";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";

import App from "./App";

describe("App", () => {
  it("should work as expected", async () => {
    const { getByTestId } = render(<App />);

    const testCheckBox = getByTestId("testing-it");
    expect(testCheckBox).not.toBeChecked();

    fireEvent.focus(testCheckBox);
    fireEvent.keyPress(testCheckBox, { // also tried with fireEvent.keyDown
      keyCode: 32,
      charCode: 32,
      key: " ", // also tried with "Space"
      code: "Space"
    });

    expect(testCheckBox).toBeChecked(); // this fails
  });
});
```

The test fails at the second expect statement- `expect(testCheckBox).toBeChecked();` However it should have passed as I focused the checkbox and pressed the Space key.

When I use `fireEvent.click()` instead of `fireEvent.keyPress()`, then the test passes.

CodeSandbox link- https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-star-6k6ghp

I have opened an issue with the same details in the **dom-testing-library** Github repo- https://github.com/testing-library/dom-testing-library/issues/1258

Asking it here to get a faster response and making the issue more visible to the developer community.

Comment: Related issue: https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/376#issuecomment-497369928